# Mac OS shell script to create markdown file in vim with date YYYY-MM-DD and hyphenated title from user input and pre-filled content

Tags: macos, shell, date, user-input

### there are a lot of "moving parts" and I am sure I am overthinking the problem to fix/finish.

Purpose of script would prompt/ask for a string stored as `$TITLE` and hyphenate spaces

(I can't even fathom where to begin to fix this part) then give a list of the next 9 Mondays in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` either select by number (enumerated list) or arrow selection.

open `vim` with a file named `YYYY-MM-DD-hyphenated-title-from-script.md`

with the following

```
---
layout:
title:
description:
---
```

here is the script I currently have

```
#! /bin/bash
next_mondays(){
    for((i=0;i<$1;i++)); do
        date -d "monday + $((i*7)) days" -I
    done
}
echo "enter blog post title"
read  TITLE
TITLE=${TITLE// /-}

cat >$FILENAME <<EOF
---
layout:
title:
description:
image: assets/img/
---

EOF
```

the current output I get is

```
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Comment: Which operating system? Bash may be common, but `date` had different option in Linux and in BSD (and so macos).

Comment: Mac OS, tags and title edited to reflect.